# codenameone IOS entitlements for multicast udp

Tags: ios, udp, codenameone, broadcasting

My UDP broadcast code for IOS mysteriously stopped working.  Code from
the same source still works on old iphones, which makes me suspect some
snafu in the build process.    According to some docs, apple requires
com.apple.developer.networking.multicast entitlement as of IOS 14.

How can I ensure this is included in the build?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64432296/756809). You need to first get approval from Apple to use multicast. We'll add the build hint:

```
ios.entitlements.multicast=true
```

Which will implement part 3 in that answer.

Comment: So adding this to my build does nothing, yet?

Comment: I got the permission from apple.  If I read the tea leaves correctly the ios entitlements build hint should end up in the info.plist file, but I do not see it there in today's build.

Comment: If you add the build hint it will work, you need to add it and send a new build.

Comment: Not working yet.  Where exactly in the sources should I see the result of the build hint?

Comment: Codesign pushes the entitlements into the binary as part of its signing process. If you added the hint manually make sure you included the `codename1.arg.` prefix.

Comment: That's what is in my build hints file.  This has no effect on the executable you build.  I'm looking for where it would be manifest in the build sources. codename1.arg.ios.enableproguard=false
codename1.arg.ios.entitlements.multicast=true
codename1.arg.ios.fastbuild=true

Comment: Grep the code for `com.apple.developer.networking.multicast` which should be in a plist there.

Comment: The entitlement phrase doesn't occur anywhere in the sources you generated

Comment: I think it's only in the signature itself. That means it's only in the binary and not in the source

Comment: It's not clear to me how this is supposed to work, but if I were building my own binaries as most apple developers do, there would have to be something in the xcode project that reflected the desire to use multicast, wouldn't there?  Then separately when apple signs the binary for purposes of the app store, it checks that you have their permission to make that request.

Comment: We generate the entitlement file outside of the project since it's a part of the signing phase then use it to sign from command line. I'm not sure if it makes sense that it's outside of the project at lease for cases of build from source. Either way I'm not sure if xcode will pick it up even if we include it in the directory

Comment: -- so how do we debug this process?  I got permission from apple, added the build hint, made new manifests, built new binaries, but my app still can't multicast.

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Comment: I found a problem in my code, this should be fixed for the next update on Friday. Sorry about the delay

Comment: no change today.  still doesn't work, still no sign of the entitlement in the sources.

Comment: Odd. I redeployed the servers, sometimes things are a bit flaky in the deployment so hopefully it's that.

Comment: Redeployed again earlier but we got feedback the problem still isn't fixed. Looking into it.

Comment: I still don't see any evidence of a multicast entitlement in the latest build sources.   Can you tell me what I should be able to see?

Comment: This isn't in the source include, only in the binary. If you unzip that the entitlement file should be in there somewhere.

Comment: I put ios.entitlements.multicast in the projectg build hints, and it is supposed to end up in the binary in the entitlements file.  There has to be some bridge in the sources that tells the build process to put it there.   Show me in one of your projects.

Comment: No. The file is used during the build process and it's only a part of the CLI. We're thinking of a way to include it into the downloaded sources but it still won't be a part of the physical project.

Comment: I see - but whatever the process is supposed to be, it's not working yet.  Latest build still gets no UDP on modern devices, but still works on old ones.

Comment: We're trying to reproduce this, unfortunately it's not something trivial to reproduce

Comment: We finally fixed this, it should work with new builds now...

Comment: Finally works.  What an ordeal for all concerned.  Thanks apple!

Answer (score 0):

The entitlement phrase doesn't occur anywhere in the sources you generate

```
guava:~ davedyer$ cd Desktop/
guava:Desktop davedyer$ cd boardspace-5.49
guava:boardspace-5.49 davedyer$ ls
dist    res
guava:boardspace-5.49 davedyer$ grep -r -i multicast *
dist/Launch-src/cn1_class_method_index.m:    "multicast" /* 384 */,
dist/Launch-src/java_net_URIHelper.h:extern JAVA_OBJECT get_static_java_net_URIHelper_MULTICAST();
dist/Launch-src/java_net_URIHelper.m:JAVA_OBJECT get_static_java_net_URIHelper_MULTICAST(CODENAME_ONE_THREAD_STATE) {
dist/Launch-src/java_net_URIHelper.m:    return STRING_FROM_CONSTANT_POOL_OFFSET(384) /* multicast */;
dist/Launch-src/java_net_URIHelper.m:    /* LDC: 'multicast'*/
dist/Launch-src/java_net_URIHelper.m:    /* LDC: 'multicast'*/
guava:boardspace-5.49 davedyer$
```